# Averaging infinite acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

At t=0, a body travels to the right at the speed of 1 m/sec.
At t=1 sec, the body travels to the left at the speed of 1 m/sec for another 1 sec.

We're asked what is the size and direction of the average acceleration.

Now, my problem with this question is that around t=1 we have infinite acceleration (instant change of direction, division by a delta t of 0 sec). How, in light of this, can one compute the average acceleration during the whole course?

**EDIT**: clarification: the body changes its direction instantaneously, i.e. in 0 sec. Correct, this can't happen in real life, but allow this for the sake of this question.

**EDIT**: I am not a student and this is definitely not a homework question, please reopen it. The question is inspired by a question in mechanics, however I was not asking for a numerical solution but for an explanation about a fundamental physics principal: circumventing the point in which the body changes direction in zero time.

Comment: @john-rennie I am not a student and this is definitely *not* a homework question, please reopen it. The question is inspired by a question in mechanics, however I was not asking for a numerical solution but for an explanation about a fundamental physics principal: circumventing the point in which the body changes direction in zero time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No one said the acceleration was instantaneous. All we know is that the velocity was $+1\,\textrm{m/s}$ at $t=0\,\textrm{s}$ and $-1\,\textrm{m/s}$ at $t=1\,\textrm{s}$. Anything could have happened during that second. The speed of the body was not necessarily constant during the time interval. The average acceleration is still well-defined.

This is similar to finding average velocity. For example: at $t=0\,\textrm{s}$, a body is at $x=10\,\textrm{m}$, at $t=10\,\textrm{s}$, the body is at $25\,\textrm{m}$. The body did not teleport from one position to another, so the average velocity calculation is perfectly defined.

Comment: And what if we explicitly add that the body changed its direction instantaneously, i.e. in 0 sec? Would it still make sense to talk about an average? See my edit to the question.

Comment: @gil_mo It is more of a mathematical exercise than a physics one. The derivative of acceleration is called jerk. You also have higher order derivative. It's too much for this comment, but I suppose this is an interesting read if you're interested in the physics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics) .

Comment: @Bernhard I was not asking about any derivative of the acceleration, but about the average, given that there's a moment in which the accel is infinite.

Comment: @gil_mo If the body changes velocity instantaneously, then the instant acceleration is infinite and we are no longer talking about physics in this universe. In your problem, the velocity changed by -2m/s over the course of 1 sec. So, your average acceleration is $\Delta v/\Delta t = -2/1 = -2\textrm{m/s}^2$.